# Avoid Extra White Space VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a userform that enters data into another userform, with data being entered on a new line for each submission. I am running into a problem where the 1st entered data skips a line on my userform. How can I adjust my code to avoid having the extra white line in the beginning, here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 opsvision.opsfinding.Value = opsvision.opsfinding.Value & vbNewLine & "Employees" & "---" & generalbuilder.employees.Value & " -" & Space(2) & Space(1) & """" & Me.findings.Value & """" & Space(5) & "----" & Space(3) & "Finding Conducted by: " & Worksheets("userform").Range("B3") & vbNewLine

Unload Me
End Sub
```

> The red line shows the extra white space at the top of the text box
>   [image: The red line shows the extra white space at the top of the text box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test to see if it's empty first. Otherwise you concatenate a `vbNewLine` to the empty starting value:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim line As String

    line = "Employees" & "---" & generalbuilder.employees.Value & " -" & Space(2) & _
        Space(1) & """" & Me.findings.Value & """" & Space(5) & "----" & Space(3) & _
        "Finding Conducted by: " & Worksheets("userform").Range("B3") & vbNewLine

    If opsvision.opsfinding.Value = vbNullString Then
        opsvision.opsfinding.Value = line
    Else
        opsvision.opsfinding.Value = opsvision.opsfinding.Value & vbNewLine & line
    End If

    Unload Me
End Sub
```